# Identifying a white elliptical shaped icon in notification bar

Tags: notification-icons

This icon is not going away. I checked my apps, and no unnecessary app has been installed. I tried rebooting, and shutting down and booting. The icon is still there. It is annoying me.

Can anyone help me remove the icon?

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 0):

If that icon appears on the notifications tab:

You could drag your notifications bar down, try clicking and holding to find out what application it is and click on the info button then 'uninstall'.